# Laravel 5.0 redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel, access-control

I am developing a custom access control system in Laravel 5.0. I have created a helper function to check if a user has permission before executing a function

```
public function index() {

    if( has_permission( 'blahblah' ) ) {
      // Do actions
    }
}
```

And I have a helper function `has_permission`

```
function has_permission( $action ) {
   $current_user_perms = array( 'view_users', 'create_users', 'edit_users', 'delete_users' );
   if( !in_array( $action, $current_user_perms ) ) {
      return redirect()->route('access_denied');
   }

   return true;
}
```

But when permission fails, it is not redirecting. Any idea?

Comment: you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **return** redirect response to make it working.

1. Change helper to return boolean value:

```php
function has_permission($action) {
    $current_user_perms = ['view_users', 'create_users', 'edit_users'];
    return in_array($action, $current_user_perms);
}
```

2. In controller check helper method and return redirect response if needed:

```php
public function index() {

    if(!has_permission('blahblah')) {
        return redirect()->route('access_denied');
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

---

PS. I highly recomend to read about [middlewares](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) and use them instead of helpers, that's the right Laravel-way to achieve simple permissions functionality.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to redirect from Helper itself?

Comment: @Corner that's not how MVC pattern works. Controller should return the response, not Helper.